# ¿Como puedo limpiar los campos de mi fomulario?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy utilizando PHPMailer, al enviar los datos al correo GMail pero luego de clickear "aceptar" en el `alert` que verifica que el correo fue enviado, mis campos siguen llenos de la informacion que mandé, ¿alguien sabe cómo puedo resetearlos?

Éste es mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>Formulario</title> <!-- Aquí va el título de la página -->

</head>

<body>
<?php

    $Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Mensaje = $_POST['Mensaje'];
    $Telefono = $_POST['Telefono'];    

    if ($Nombre=='' || $Email=='' || $Mensaje=='' || $Telefono==''){

        echo "<script>alert('Los campos marcados con * son obligatorios');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";

    }else{


        require("archivosformulario/class.phpmailer.php");
        $mail = new PHPMailer();    
        $mail->From     = $Email;
        $mail->FromName = $Nombre; 
        $mail->AddAddress("ejemplo@gmail.com"); // Dirección a la que llegaran los mensajes.

        // Aquí van los datos que apareceran en el correo que reciba
        //adjuntamos un archivo 

        $mail->WordWrap = 50; 
        $mail->IsHTML(true);     
        $mail->Subject  =  "Comentarios Tiendas El Golazo";
        $mail->Body     =  "Nombre: $Nombre \n<br />".    
        "Email: $Email \n<br />".    
        "Mensaje: $Mensaje \n<br />".
        "Telefono: $Telefono \n<br />";       

        // Datos del servidor SMTP

        $mail->IsSMTP(); 
        $mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465";  // Servidor de Salida.
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
        $mail->Username = "ejemplo@gmail.com";  // Correo Electrónico
        $mail->Password = ""; // Contraseña

        if ($mail->Send())
        echo "<script>alert('Formulario enviado exitosamente, le responderemos lo más pronto posible.');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";    

        else
        echo "<script>alert('Error al enviar el formulario');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";

    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Así se visualiza al enviar la información y deseo saber cómo limpiarlo después del `alert`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Cómo se crea el formulario?

Comment: ¿Te refieres al Código?

Comment: Acabo de ver que haces history.back y ahí es dónde está el quid de la cuestión

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está aquí:

```
if ($mail->Send())
echo "<script>alert('Formulario enviado exitosamente, le responderemos lo más pronto posible.');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";    

else
echo "<script>alert('Error al enviar el formulario');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";
```

Y en concreto en esta parte de aquí: `location.href ='javascript:history.back()` (que por cierto podrías simplificar para que fuese sólo `history.back()`), porque lo que estás haciendo es decirle al navegador que vaya un paso atrás en el historial (a la página del formulario). Entonces el navegador retrocederá un paso en el historial pero generalmente mantendrá la información introducida por el usuario (que es lo que quieres evitar).

Podrías solucionar esto de diferentes maneras:

- En lugar de hacer `history.back()`, usa el `location.href` para redireccionar a la página que contenga el formulario directamente (p.e.: `location.href='pagina_formulario.php'`). Este método hará que en lugar de cargarse la página que hay en la caché, se genere una nueva con el formulario en blanco.
- Usa el evento [`pageshow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pageshow) de la ventana para limpiar el formulario. Este evento se ejecuta siempre que se atraviesa el historial (al cargar una página nueva o al pulsar los botones de adelante/atrás).

  El código JavaScript sería muy simple e iría en la página del formulario (después de que el formulario se haya cargado):

  ```
  <script>
  // cuando se muestre la página
  window.addEventListener('pageshow', function(event) {
      // borra el formulario (asumiendo que sólo hay uno; si hay más, especifica su Id)
      document.querySelector("form").reset();
  });
  </script>
  ```

Comment: Muchas gracias esa opción habia elegido y si era ese el problema agradezco mucho la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

A traves de javascript el metodo reset(), para resetear el formulario por ejemplo:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

Comment: ¿Dónde lo coloco? ¿En un script a parte?

Comment: puedes ponerlo despues del alert() que envias.

Comment: Esto no funcionaría al hacerlo después del `alert`, porque estarías limpiando el formulario en una página en la que el formulario no existe (existe en la anterior, no en la actual)

Comment: Tienes razón, no me fije en eso, pensé que todo lo estaba manejando con js.